# Does Cassandra's commit log have a write amplification problem when placed on SSDs?

Tags: cassandra

AFAIK, when Cassandra does a write, it writes to the Memtable as well as writing to the commit log on disk (appending).  If the commit message is very small, too small to fill up a SSD page, won't this cause some fragmentation and write amplification in the long run? (After disk fills up)

Answer (score 0):

This datastax article may answer your question:
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/updates-to-cassandras-commit-log-in-2-2

Specifically:

> Since version 1.1 a feature of the commit log infrastructure in Cassandra has been the ability to reuse segments. This is done in order to reduce fragmentation on the logging drive -- a number of commitlog segments will be kept reserved by the database for overwriting after the data they contain has been flushed, which means that most of the time the commit log will not need to allocate new space in order to write. This does not eliminate all fragmentation that can be caused by the log, as it will continue writing after its space quota has been reached while memtable flushes are in progress, and afterwards it will release the overallocated space. Still, since less space is allocated and freed, there is a lower chance of introducing fragmentation on the drive.